# Conversion files from XLS to CSV

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, batch-processing

I m trying to prepare a script which cnvert all the files xls to csv but i gt this error when I tried to run it

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open ../public/mad/export_tarifs.xls for reading! File does not exist.' in C:\wamp\www\chaima\speed-wear.net\web\batchs\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel5.php on line 443

And this is my code below :

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = '../public/mad/test_batch_solsys.xls';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
    $objWriter->save($loadedSheetName.'.csv');
}
```

Comment: So where does the file you want to read **actually live**???

Comment: add the full file path to $inputFileName.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, you error quotes `../public/mad/export_tarifs.xls` and your code suggests the file is called `../public/mad/test_batch_solsys.xls` what should we believe?

Comment: I correct the paths but I still have an error you will find it below